# Split XML and transform it in one or more SOAP Envelope

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

**TL;DR; Sequence receives an XML message and I need to build many SOAP Envelope  according to the number of `<product>` tags I received.**

I have a sequence that receives this following XML (**Message 1**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pricing>
    <product>
        <idFF>1</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>abc</skuPartner>        
        <original>123</original>        
        <new>123</new>      
    </product>
    <product>
        <idFF>2</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>aba</skuPartner>        
        <original>123</original>        
        <new>123</new>      
    </product>
    <product>
        <idFF>3</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>ae</skuPartner>        
        <original>123</original>        
        <new>123</new>      
    </product>
</pricing>
```

I would like to iterate in this message and for each `<product>` node make a call to a SOAP Service using the following contract:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:ProductPriceUpdate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:safeKey>?</tem:safeKey>
         <tem:storeId>?</tem:storeId>
         <tem:articleId>?</tem:articleId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:barcode>?</tem:barcode>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:sku>?</tem:sku>
         <tem:price>?</tem:price>
         <tem:discount>?</tem:discount>
      </tem:ProductPriceUpdate>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this message above,  I need to replace

```
<tem:articleId>?</tem:articleId>
<tem:sku>?</tem:sku>
<tem:price>?</tem:price>
```

with the values contained in the nodes from the XML message received

```
<idFF>1</idFF>        
<skuPartner>abc</skuPartner>                
<new>123</new>
```

So, facing the problem described I did (at least tried to):

- Iterate over the message (**Message 1**) received
- Take the values from the nodes `<idFF> <skuPartner> <new>`
- Build a SOAP Envelope using PayloadFactory
- Call SOAP service

I am pretty sure that I am little bit far from the solution. This is what I've tried.

```
<iterate expression="//produto" id="iterateXML" sequential="true xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <ProductPriceUpdate>
                            <safeKey>nExd8CzMRDo=</safeKey>
                            <storeId>123</storeId>
                            <articleId>$1</articleId>
                            <barcode>1</barcode>
                            <sku>$2</sku>
                            <price>$3</price>
                            <discount>1</discount>
                        </ProductPriceUpdate>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//idFF"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//skuPartner"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//new"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <callout action="ProductPriceUpdate"
                    initAxis2ClientOptions="false" serviceURL="http://url-url.url.info/pub/url.asmx">
                    <source xpath="*"/>
                    <target key="Result"/>
                </callout>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
```

This is the output from the console:

```
[2016-02-11 11:04:52,982] ERROR - SequenceMediator Expecting an implementation of SOAP Envelope as the parent. But received some other implementation
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Expecting an implementation of SOAP Envelope as the parent. But received some other implementation
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPHeaderImpl.checkParent(SOAPHeaderImpl.java:408)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPElement.setParent(SOAPElement.java:81)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:296)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.addChild(OMElementImpl.java:212)
        at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPBodyImpl.addChild(SOAPBodyImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.CalloutMediator.mediate(CalloutMediator.java:161)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.Target.mediate(Target.java:106)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:163)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorWorker.run(MediatorWorker.java:69)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-02-11 11:04:53,031]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:481ca0ce-8502-486a-b501-350bda23f263, Di
rection: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Expecting an implementation of SOAP Envelope as the parent. But
received some other implementation, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body><pricing>
        <product>
        <idFF>1</idFF>
        <skuPartner>abc</skuPartner>
        <original>123</original>
        <new>123</new>
    </product>
    <product>
        <idFF>2</idFF>
        <skuPartner>aba</skuPartner>
        <original>123</original>
        <new>123</new>
    </product>
    <product>
        <idFF>3</idFF>
        <skuPartner>ae</skuPartner>
        <original>123</original>
        <new>123</new>
    </product>
</pricing></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I am missing? Should I use another mediator like **Enrich**? 
I appreciate every tip, thank you. =)

**EDIT:**

As suggested by @Jean-Michel, I replaced the xpath expression in callout mediator and the error of SOAP implementation, gone. Although I am still not able to do the request. When I go to the Monitor -> SOAP trace of my WSO2 I see the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">IDFF;SKUPARTNER;ORIGINAL;NEW&#xd;11035073;BOBSKU11035073;185.99;200&#xd;</text>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**EDIT 2:**

After some modification, I just realized that the message I am sending in the callout mediator is the same message inside a SOAP envelope that I receive in the begining of the sequence. As it follows (please do not consider the xpath error, it was intentional):

```
[2016-02-11 12:44:43,197]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:c3bda9c7-157e-46db-ae9f-f5b687d11848, Di
rection: request, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = The evaluation of the XPath expression : body did not result in
an OMElement, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><pricing>
        <product>
        <idFF>1</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>abc</skuPartner>        
        <original>123</original>        
        <new>123</new>      
    </product>
    <product>
        <idFF>2</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>aba</skuPartner>        
        <original>123</original>        
        <new>123</new>      
    </product>
    <product>
        <idFF>3</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>ae</skuPartner>        
        <original>123</original>        
        <new>123</new>      
    </product>
</pricing></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**EDIT 3:**

I changed the address of the callout to the http://localhost:1205 and this is the result using TCPMon. Seems that everything is alright.

[image: TCPMon Result]

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. The xpath is not returning the values? The payload is wrong? Some error occurs?

Comment: I just forgot to attach the output. My bad. I'm going to edit.

Comment: Seems like the payload generated with payloadFactory is not in a valid soap envelope. Use a xslt transform instead of, or try setting the soapAction berofe the callout.

Comment: Thank you @elias. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. Thank you @Jean-Michel for helping me through.

I did the following:

- Created a PassThrough Proxy
- Changed the Callout Mediator to a Send Mediator invoking the PassThroug Proxy
- Added a Header Mediator and defined the SOAP Action - **MOST IMPORTANT!**

Here you can find my WSO2-Config.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <registry provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.registry.WSO2Registry">
        <parameter name="cachableDuration">15000</parameter>
    </registry>
    <taskManager provider="org.wso2.carbon.mediation.ntask.NTaskTaskManager"/>
    <proxy name="smook_proxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https http vfs">
        <description/>
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2"
                    type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <clone>
                    <target sequence="pricing"/>
                </clone>
            </inSequence>
        </target>
        <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///C:\Users\victor.viola\Desktop\out</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///C:\Users\victor.viola\Desktop\in</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///C:\Users\victor.viola\Desktop\error</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.csv</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    </proxy>

    <proxy name="PS_PRICING" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https http">
        <description/>
        <target>
            <endpoint name="wsFF">
                <address trace="disable" uri="ADRESSTOTHEBACKEND.asmx"/>
            </endpoint>
            <inSequence/>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence/>
        </target>
    </proxy>

    <localEntry key="smooks-csv.xml" src="file:C:/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/resources/smooks/smooks-csv.xml">
        <description/>
    </localEntry>
    <endpoint name="PS_PRICING">
        <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/PS_PRICING"/>
    </endpoint>

    <sequence name="pricing" statistics="enable" trace="enable">
        <smooks config-key="smooks-csv.xml">
            <input type="text"/>
            <output type="xml"/>
        </smooks>
        <iterate expression="//product" id="iterateXML"
            sequential="true" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                        <format>
                            <ProductPriceUpdate>
                                <safeKey>******</safeKey>
                                <storeId>*****</storeId>
                                <articleId>$1</articleId>
                                <barcode/>
                                <sku>$2</sku>
                                <price>$3</price>
                                <discount>100</discount>
                            </ProductPriceUpdate>
                        </format>
                        <args>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//idFF"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//skuPartner"/>
                            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//new"/>
                        </args>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="text/xml"/>
                    <in>
                        <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://tempuri.org/ProductPriceUpdate"/>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint key="PS_PRICING"/>
                        </send>
                        <drop/>
                    </in>
                    <out>
                        <send/>
                    </out>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </iterate>
    </sequence>
</definitions>
```

Here is my smooks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:file="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/file-routing-1.1.xsd">
  <params>
    <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    <param name="default.serialization.on">true</param>
  </params>
  <csv:reader fields="idFF,skuPartner,original,new" separator=";" skipLines="1"/>
  <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="#document">
    <ftl:template><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pricing>
    <#list .vars["csv-set"]["csv-record"] as csv_record>
    <product>
        <idFF>${.vars["csv_record"]["idFF"]}</idFF>        
        <skuPartner>${.vars["csv_record"]["skuPartner"]}</skuPartner>        
        <original>${.vars["csv_record"]["original"]}</original>        
        <new>${.vars["csv_record"]["new"]}</new>      
    </product>
    </#list>    
</pricing>]]></ftl:template>
  </ftl:freemarker>
  <resource-config selector="#document">
    <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
  </resource-config>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

Another thing that was VERY important to solve the issue was enabling these two logs in log4j.properties (wso2home/repository/conf)

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.headers=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used with callout mediator, but `<source xpath="*"/>` seems strange : it means "all nodes for the source payload" (message that must be sent).

You should consider something like `<source xpath="$body/*[1]"/>` to send the first body's child (ie the content of the current soap body) for exemple...

Comment: Thank you @Jean-Michel. I'm going to try this now.

Comment: This is because the current content Type is "text/plain", you can change it before sending your message setting this property : <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/> for exemple (depending on what is required for you backend service)

Comment: Thank you again. I did some modification here and I just realized that the message I am sending in the callout is not going correctly. It's going exactly the same way I received in the very begining of the sequence. Seems like I am not "saving" or "creating" new messages. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Again, seems strange because in your question, we can see that the callout is inside an iterate, and inside this iterate, you use payloadFactory before using callout => 1- there must have //produto nodes in your payload or iterate would not execute it's child sequence  and 2- your payloadFactory must generate the xml message starting with 'ProductPriceUpdate' : use <log level="full"/> before callout mediator...

Comment: Log full before de callout mediator - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:07bf55c5-9b2d-430a-85f0-b2761d8138a9, Di
rection: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><Pro
ductPriceUpdate xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"><safeKey>nExd8CzMRDo=</safeKey><storeId>9441</storeId><articleId>11035073</articleId><sku>BOBSKU11035073
</sku><price>200</price><discount>100</discount></ProductPriceUpdate></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: So, in the log before the callout everything looks fine.

Comment: use tcpmon (delivered with WSO2 ESB, see ESB_HOME/bin) between the ESB and your service : you will see what callout really send